# Cocos2D: How to use Mask Image

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, alpha, masking, pvrtc

I am using cocos2d for a game which uses sprite sheets for my character animations. I created these images using TexturePacker. Now, I want to use PVRTC 4 format for reducing memory consumption due to some reasons. But as the [PVRTC Texture Compression 
Usage Guide](http://mobile-opus.com/OGLES/SDKPackage_OGLES2/Utilities/PVRTexLib/Documentation/PVRTC%20Texture%20Compression.Usage%20Guide.1.7f.External.pdf) suggests, I need to add extra border of 4 pixels in each character to produce proper results. Even if I add border, I will have to mask this image with alpha image to remove border at run time. I am using Texture Packer to create a sprite sheet with PVRTC4 format and created alpha masking image matching it. I am ready with these 2 images in hand which are of same width and height.

Now my question is, how can I mask my PVRTC texture with alpha image in Cocos2D?

It will be more helpful if the solution provided works with Batch Nodes!

Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Comment: Now I came to know that their is an image format named PVR-A8 which can be used for these king of needs. I have converted my alpha image to this this format and also able to load this image in Cocos2D. But still they act as two separate images and doesn't mask with each other to create one single texture. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the border/padding area completely transparent?

Comment: The border is made corrupt by the compression technique they use. Thats why they recommend adding border with matching color, so the extra border gets corrupt and texture remains intact. This is explained in the last part of usage guide (link shared above). So as a result, I need to mask it with other image! :(

Comment: Since you are using 4bpp, the compressor should be able to choose a completely transparent setting for the pixels in your transparent border.

Comment: sigh.. edit period timed out. I forgot to add:
 Mind you, PVRTC(-I) does assume non-premultiplied colour for the "fully transparent" pixel option so its effectiveness may depend on what colour you've used for the fully transparent pixels in your source texture. 
Out of curiosity, do you have regions/pixels where the texture is partially transparent?

Comment: Yes.. the border of the character animations are partially transparent. This is just for the sake of removing the glitches and make it feel like smooth and anti-aliased!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and after reading ray wenderlichs page about masking, I made a little ccsprite subclass which allows you to mask by 2 images.

[CCMaskedSprite](https://github.com/renevdkooi/CCMaskedSprite)